# Visual Basic Radio Button Authentication Mistake

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, loops, object, for-loop

I'm using visual basic to create a program that records hourly and salary employees derived from an abstract base class. For my interface the user will select either hourly or salary employee and if hourly the form displays hours and hourly rate text boxes. If salary the form hides the hours textbox and changes hourly rate to annual salary.

I have a loop setup as follows:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To EmployeeList.Count - 1
        Dim thisEmployee As Employee = EmployeeList(i)

        Dim HourlyorAnnualrate As String = Nothing
        Dim Hours As String = Nothing


        If TypeOf (thisEmployee) Is HourlyEmployee Then
            HourlyorAnnualrate = CType(thisEmployee, HourlyEmployee).decRate
            Hours = CType(thisEmployee, HourlyEmployee).decHours
            TotalHourlyRate += thisEmployee.WeeklyGrossPay()

        End If

        If TypeOf (thisEmployee) Is SalariesEmployee Then
            HourlyorAnnualrate = CType(thisEmployee, SalariesEmployee).decSalary
            TotalSalariesRate += thisEmployee.WeeklyGrossPay()
        End If
```

I am adding info to a textbox on buttonclick with the following:

```
 Private Sub btnPayroll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPayroll.Click
    txtRecord.Text = "Total number of employees: " & vbTab & vbTab & EmployeeList.Count & vbCrLf & _
                     "Number of salaries employees: " & vbTab & SalariesEmployeeList.Count & vbCrLf & _
                     "Number of hourly employees: " & vbTab & vbTab & HourlyEmployeeList.Count & vbCrLf & _
                     "Total salaries employee weekly payroll: " & vbTab & vbTab & FormatCurrency(TotalSalariesRate) & vbCrLf & _
                     "Total hourly employee weekly payroll: " & vbTab & vbTab & FormatCurrency(TotalHourlyRate) & vbCrLf & _
                     "Total weekly payroll: " & vbTab & vbTab & FormatCurrency(TotalSalariesRate + TotalHourlyRate)





End Sub
```

The problem I am running into is that a user can select a salary employee and it works just fine but if they then select an hourly employee the weeklygrosspay is recorded and added to both TotalSalaries rate and TotalHourlyRate.

Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening? I tried un-checking the radio buttons after each button click but since this is in a loop I it still will record incorrectly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you mind posting the form code that handles/displays the values the loop is setting up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the values in the sub procedure to 0 and it works great now!